# Inner product space and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

We introduce $f ∈ V$ (where $V = C([0,1],\mathbb R)$), and we put $a_n = <f, e_n>$ (where $e_n$ is an orthonormal sequence in $V$).

Assuming $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^∞ a_n  e_n(x)$ is continuous, we have to show that $g = f$.
The sum here is with respect to the norm $|| · ||$ generated
by $<·,·>$ and hence $\lim\limits_{N \to ∞}\||g(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n  e_n(x)|| = 0$

I am not sure how to approach the problem, from what I think is I have to show that the sum converges to $f ∈ V$ in the complete inner product space $V$, and thus $f = g$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Write down $\|f-g\|$ and see if you can argue that this is zero.